# TabLayout removing using removeTabAt() causes NullPointerException: void android.view.View.unFocus(android.view.View)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-tablayout, tablayout

[image: I was trying to remove a tab from Tablayout but I was generating a Nullpointer exception.]

I was using this code to remove a tab element . Of course I validate if the tab is null and the  tab count. But I still receiving that error.

```
rootBinding?.tabs?.removeTabAt(TOYS_TAB_POSITION_INDEX)
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it doing the following:

```
    rootBinding?.tabs?.let { tabs ->

      val toyTab = tabs.getTabAt(TOYS_TAB_POSITION_INDEX)

      toyTab?.let { tabToDelete ->

        tabToDelete.view.clearFocus()

        rootBinding?.tabs?.removeTab(tabToDelete)

      }

    }

  It fix my crash ;) .. Any comment or doubt let me know
```